# run C gdb over .so files via tkcon

Tags: c, gdb, swig

I have `.so` dynamic library file that is loaded to a `tkcon` console.
This `.so` dynamic library file was written in C code. (I wrapped the code with `swig` compilation)

I'd like to debug this C code of the `.so` dynamic library with `gdb`.

Is it possible to do so?
If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

If your .so library is compiled with debug symbols then it is straight forward but if it doesn't then you have to use symbol table to debug.

Comment: What do you mean by "straight forward"? I compiled with debug symbols, but I don't know how shall I launch the GDB.
To be more precise. GDB looks for executable file but in the tkcon prompt I have available C functions which I have exposed via the .i file wrapper.